# System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException : SQL Logic Error

Tags: c#, database, sqlite

A Sqlite Database was created that consists on a persons FirstName and LastName.When the code is executed, **System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteException: 'SQL logic error
no such table: Person'**  is shown at code  :

```
*var output = cnn.Query<ListPeopleModel>(" Select * from Person;", new DynamicParameters());    
return output.ToList();*
```

where `Person` is the name of my database and *ListPeopleModel* is my Model Class.
.

Comment: A Database contains _tables_ and the Sql statement _select_ reads _tables_. If Person is a database then Select needs a table name inside the Person database.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses the name of the class you use to construct the database as the table. So just replace:

```
" Select * from Person;"
```

with:

```
" Select * from ListPeopleModel;"
```